# Remove duplicates when values equal or subset each other in Saprk dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to remove duplicates in Spark dataset only if the values in the same column are the same or subset of each other.
Example:

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Newyork City |
| 2 | Berlin DE |
| 3 | Berlin |
| 4 | Newyork City US |
| 5 | Paris FR |
| 6 | Paris |

I would like the output like this:

| ID | DATA |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | Newyork City US |
| 3 | Berlin |
| 6 | Paris |

Could any one help in this issue? Java Spark example is fine, also in other language is wellcome.
Note: in the duplicate records the record with max ID will be picked.

Comment: How do you determine a subset? Is starting with the same letter a subset? 
Or does it have to be delimited by a space? Also, I notice that you're taking the longer version (with 3 words when there is one with 2 words) for "Newyork City US" but using the shorter version (with 1 word when there is one with 2 words) for "Berlin". Is there a reason why this is not consistent?

Comment: the number of words dosn't matter, in the duplicate records, I want to keep the record with max ID.

Comment: @Darsh I want to know some special cases to confirm, for example, does "A B C" and "A B D" in the same "subset"? What about "Newyork X City" and "Newyork City"?

Comment: the condition is: if the values in the column DATA is equal or subset of anothe one, then the are dupplicates.  example:  "Newyork City" , "Newyork City US", " US Newyork City", and "X Newyork City US" are duplicates, but  "Newyork X City" and "Newyork City" are not duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my answer, the key is to join the original dataset with itself, with a specific condition (two Data columns is the substring of each other)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object SOFSpark extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("DuplicateRemovalExample")
    .master("local")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  // Create the original dataset
  val dataset = Seq(
    (1, "Newyork City"),
    (2, "Berlin DE"),
    (3, "Berlin"),
    (4, "Newyork City US"),
    (5, "Paris FR"),
    (6, "Paris")
  ).toDF("ID", "DATA")

  // Define a user-defined function (UDF) to check if one string is a substring of another. Here is the key thing
  val isSubstring = udf((str1: String, str2: String) => str1.contains(str2) || str2.contains(str1))

  // Join the original dataset with itself, with the condition is the udf function above
  val substringDataset = dataset.as("d1")
    .join(dataset.as("d2"), isSubstring($"d1.DATA", $"d2.DATA"))
    .select($"d1.ID".alias("ID1"), $"d1.DATA".alias("DATA1"), $"d2.ID".alias("ID2"), $"d2.DATA".alias("DATA2"))

  substringDataset.show()
//  +---+---------------+---+---------------+
//  |ID1|          DATA1|ID2|          DATA2|
//  +---+---------------+---+---------------+
//  |  1|   Newyork City|  1|   Newyork City|
//  |  1|   Newyork City|  4|Newyork City US|
//  |  2|      Berlin DE|  2|      Berlin DE|
//  |  2|      Berlin DE|  3|         Berlin|
//  |  3|         Berlin|  2|      Berlin DE|
//  |  3|         Berlin|  3|         Berlin|
//  |  4|Newyork City US|  1|   Newyork City|
//  |  4|Newyork City US|  4|Newyork City US|
//  |  5|       Paris FR|  5|       Paris FR|
//  |  5|       Paris FR|  6|          Paris|
//  |  6|          Paris|  5|       Paris FR|
//  |  6|          Paris|  6|          Paris|
//  +---+---------------+---+---------------+

  // Filter so that only larger Id remain
  val filterSubstringDataset = substringDataset.filter(col("ID1") > col("ID2"))
    .select(col("ID1"), col("DATA1"))
  filterSubstringDataset.show()

//  +---+---------------+
//  |ID1|          DATA1|
//  +---+---------------+
//  |  3|         Berlin|
//  |  4|Newyork City US|
//  |  6|          Paris|
//  +---+---------------+
}
```